# Schengen Visa Valid on arrival in Schengen State and not while boarding flight

Tags: transit, poland, norway, wizz-air

I am resident of Dubai and would be travelling to Poland on 21st May at around 22:30 ,my flight lands in Poland on 22nd at around 2:30 AM which is when my schengen visa becomes valid . I am very uncertain whether I would be allowed to board the flight?

If the answer is no then what would be your suggestion to get this sorted , contacting Embassy ?

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the airline to let you board the flight, just call them and ask what their policy is, personally I have been both rejected once when going to China and allowed once when going to Australia in the same situation and it has nothing to do with Schengen and all to do whether the airline requires your visa to be valid at the time of boarding or at the time of landing at your destination.

If they answer from the airline is no you need contacting the issuer of the visa and see if you can get a new one with the correct date for departure or change your flight one day later

Comment: Great I think I have got the answer , I wouldn't try my luck here as I have made commitments for the hotels , itinerary, I am flying with Wizz Air from Dubai when I called them they said you need valid travel documents ,it is upto the border crossing officer to allow or deny boarding . We have this EID scanning system which allows you to travel through E gates without getting your passport stamped .